# laravel query builder remove where clause

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

I have whereIn in Query Builder (Laravel 5.6)

```
$data->whereIn('field1', [1,2,3])->whereIn('field2', [4,5,6])->whereIn('field3', [8,9,10]);
....
$some_count = clone $data;
$result = $data->get();
$count_result = $some_count->count(); <-- need without one of whereIn
```

And now, I need to do count() without one of whereIn, for example "whereIn('field2', [4,5,6])". How to remove this clause from $some_count?

Comment: Is this an actual question?  Why can't you just remove one of the calls to `whereIn`?

Comment: how to remove it from $some_count variable?